# Program is misreading my input

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner, do-while

So.   I'm doing a tutorial on java and playing with making a D&D character sheet saver. The problem I'm having is not a serious one but after I've commanded it to load, it does the message as expected but then when I input 'new' and hit enter it waits until I hit enter again and then it does my else code instead of my if for "new".  I end up having to type it again.

```
do {
        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("new")) {
            System.out.println("Let's create a character!\n");
```

*then a bunch of other code that doesn't matter and then:*

```
    // LOAD CHARACTER
        else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("load")) {
            // placeholder for load char.
            System.out
                    .println("This is where we will load a character in the     future.  For now it is empty, please select new.");
            command = text.nextLine();
            // EXIT CODE
        } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
            System.exit(0);

            // Invalid Response
        } else
            System.out.println("Invalid response. Please try again. ");
        command = text.nextLine();
    } while (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"));
```

and here's how it comes out:

Please say 'New' for a new character or 'Load' to load a previously saved character...
*Load*
This is where we will load a character in the future.  For now it is empty, please select new.
*new*
Invalid response. Please try again. 
*new*
Let's create a character!
What is this character's name?

Comment: also, it doesn't have the problem if I go straight to new.

Comment: how about u **print command object** so we can read what value it has :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `command = text.nextLine();` in both your 'load' if section and at the end of the loop.  The first input is taken in the if block, then the blank line is read and is what gets compared in your if/else stream for the next round.

Putting the input reading outside the if-else chain is the preferable way to do it, since you don't have duplicate code in each else block.

```
do {
    if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("new")) {/*do new stuff*/} 
    else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("load")) {/*do load stuff*/}
    else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {/*do exit stuff*/}
    else {/*do default/bad input stuff*/}

    //This line runs every loop iteration(unless one of your if blocks calls break or exit
    command = text.nextLine();
} while (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"));
```

Comment: Your last `command = text.nextLine();` isn't in the if-else chain at all.  Your final `else` only prints a message since it has no {} block.  That is actually the preferable way to putting it into every else block.

Comment: It's probably better to leave the input outside of the else block.  See the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

After printing `This is where we will load ...`, you read input twice before checking the input again. Once immediately after the message, and again at the end of the loop.